# How to connect odoo with magento 2.2?

Tags: error, magento2.2, soap-api-v2

I need connect **odoo** with **magento 2.2**, and I get some result but I got and 401 error when I try to call one service with my generated token.
So far:

```
from suds.client import Client
url="https://myserver.com/soap/default?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1"
client = Client(url)
result = client.service.integrationAdminTokenServiceV1CreateAdminAccessToken('user', 'pass')
```

That result store a token to do the authentication, like http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/soap/soap-web-api-calls.html, but, when I try

```
msg = str('Bearer '+result)
header = {'Authorization': msg}
target_url = "https://myserver.com/soap?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1"
client = Client(target_url, headers=header)
```

I got Transport Error:

> HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import urllib
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1        

    def _mage_call(self, credentials):
        f = { 
        'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]':'created_at', 
        'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]':'2017-12-12', 
        'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]':'gt',
        'searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]':'increment_id', 
        'searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]':'000000001,000000002', 
        'searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]':'in'
        }

        method = 'orders?'+urllib.urlencode(f)
        auth = OAuth1(credentials['consumer_key'], credentials['consumer_secret'],credentials['access_token'], credentials['access_token_secret'])            
        result = requests.get(credentials['url']+method, auth=auth, verify=False)
        return result.text
```

Answer (score 0):

We are going to discuss the connector which can synchronize the data between Odoo and Magento (an open-source eCommerce platform). This connector also includes some important areas. This connector transfers the data from Magento to [Odoo](https://www.odoocustomization.com) with a single button click and provides Automatic Fetching of Data once connected.